# GoogleMapWidgetV3 for vaadin 6

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, vaadin

I have a problem!

When I have add GoogleMapWidgetV3 add-on (version 0.0.4) in my application(also i trying in test vaadin 6 application), It can't compile widgetset! 
Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/maps/Maps.gwt.xml' on your classpath
I have added gwt-maps.jar but it's doesn't help!

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about vaadin, but for gwt application you must inherit this xml in your project.gwt.xml file something like below,

Also, I am not sure if its Maps.gwt.xml as I have been using GoogleMaps.gwt.xml instead and this is the xml present in gwt-maps.jar

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all, check the instructions from https://github.com/wilds/GoogleMapWidgetV3:

1) Copy [vaadin-googlemapwidgetv3-0.0.4.jar](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/googlemapwidgetv3), [WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-ajaxloader-1.1.0.jar](https://github.com/wilds/GoogleMapWidgetV3/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-ajaxloader-1.1.0.jar) and [WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-maps-api-3.10.0-alpha-6.jar](https://github.com/wilds/GoogleMapWidgetV3/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-maps-api-3.10.0-alpha-6.jar) to your ROOT/WEB-INF/lib.

2) Now inherit following module in your Widgetset.gwt.xml file: **com.wildboar.vaadin.addon.googlemap.GoogleMapWidgetset**

3) Compile your projekt again.